# Phonegap change image src with jquery not working on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I try to change the src of a img tag with jquery. In firefox it is working fine, but in the phonegap developer app on android, nothing happens.

What I'm doing:

I'm getting an image as base64 with a ajax request. If the request is complete, I'm making an URL Object from the image, and change the src of the img tag to the url Object. Here my code:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: MySecretPHPFunctionOnAServerThatReturnsABase64Image..., 
        complete: function(data) {
            var base64Image = data.responseText;
            var image = makeUrlObject(base64Image, "image/jpeg");

            // ERROR!!! :-)
            // Only working in Browser, not on android... 
            $("#scanPreview").prop("src", image  + '?' + genTimestamp());
        },
        error: function() {}
    });
```

I think the makeUrlObject Function is not the reason for the error, but if you want to see it, for making sure, or if I'm overlooking something ;-)

```
    function makeUrlObject(dataURL, typeURL) {        
        var binStr = atob(dataURL);
        var buf = new ArrayBuffer(binStr.length);
        var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
        for(var i = 0; i < view.length; i++)
            view[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);

        var blob = new Blob([view], {type: typeURL});

        binStr=null;
        buf = null;
        view = null;

        URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

        return URL.createObjectURL(blob);    
   };
```

Comment: please print log of image variable. so you will get idea it's because of url or problem in image src.

Comment: The base64Image and the url are looking like I expected.

Comment: you are getting correct path in image variable so why you append genTimestamp() function. may be problem is in this function. can you please add this function also and check what it return

Comment: And also try this one may be it useful for you
$("#scanPreview").attr('src', image  + '?' + genTimestamp());

Comment: I tried already. But it is not working :-(

Comment: The genTimestamp function just uses the getTime function. But without timestamp, it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of .prop("src"

try

var elem = document.getElementById('myimg');
myimg.src="theimage.jpg";

also case sensitive